# brics_actuator.msg only works with rostopic

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm fairly new to ROS and the youBot. I'm trying to move Joint 1 of the arm. A notebook is connected via ssh to the youBot. When I use rostopic everything works as expected and the arm moves.

> rostopic pub -1 /arm_1/arm_controller/position_command brics_actuator/JointPositions '{positions:[{joint_uri: arm_joint_1, unit: rad, value: 2}]}

ros_graph looks like this:

> /rostopic_3016_lotofnumbers -> /arm_1/arm_controller/position_command -> /youbot_driver

Now I tried my own program "ArmVorlage".py, but it isn't moving:

```
class Goto_Searchposition():
def __init__(self):
    # Give the node a name
    self.node_name = "goto_searchposition"
    # Set rospy to execute a shutdown function when exiting       
    rospy.on_shutdown(self.shutdown)
    self.pub = rospy.Publisher("/arm_1/arm_controller/position_command", brics_actuator.msg.JointPositions)
    rospy.init_node("goto_searchposition")        
    joint_positions = brics_actuator.msg.JointPositions()
    JointValue = brics_actuator.msg.JointValue()
    JointValue.joint_uri='arm_joint_1'
    JointValue.unit = 'rad'
    JointValue.value = 2
    joint_positions.positions.append(JointValue)
    self.pub.publish(joint_positions)
    rospy.sleep(1)
    rospy.loginfo(str(joint_positions))      
def shutdown(self):
    # Always stop the robot when shutting down the node.
    rospy.loginfo("Stopping the robot...")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Goto_Searchposition()
    rospy.spin()
```

ros_graph looks like this:

> /goto_searchposition -> /arm_1/arm_controller/position_command -> /youbot_driver

The debugging in /youbot_driver looks similiar except the ports are different and these logs are missing when running my own program:

> [DEBUG] [1399616158.709991323]: Command for arm1 received

> [DEBUG] [1399616158.710137675]: Arm ID is: youbot-manipulator

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Regards

Timo
(I'm sorry i cant post pictures or links cause as a new user i have too little karma)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/162976/brics_actuator.msg-only-works-with-rostopic/) by [cobhc999](https://answers.ros.org/users/14666/cobhc999/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2014-05-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on 2014-06-11**:
I have a similar doubt. Though I am getting a different error. Will just "from brics_actuator import JointPosition" work? I just made a python script and get this:
http://answers.ros.org/question/173395/controlling-youbots-arm-brics_actuatorjointpositions/

youbot@youbot-desktop:~$ rosrun youbot_leap leap_armcontrol.py Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/youbot/catkin_ws/src/youbotleap/scripts/leap_armcontrol.py", line 96, in  sender() File "/home/youbot/catkin_ws/src/youbotleap/scripts/leap_armcontrol.py", line 25, in sender msg.positions.joint_uri = "arm_joint_1" AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'joint_uri'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved it by changing 'rad' to "rad". Unfortunately there was never an error message or something.

---

Originally posted by [cobhc999](https://answers.ros.org/users/14666/cobhc999/) with karma: 38 on 2014-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0